# How do I find new drivers for my laptop in RHEL WS 6.4?

Tags: rhel, drivers

I recently installed Redhat workstation 6.4 on my laptop as some of the stuff we're doing in class uses Linux (we have an [RPi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) that we're learning the C language on). I figured, since the school has RHEL free for students, I would try that distro hoping that there would be additional support and stuff like that over the free versions.

So, everything works and I have an internet connection but I'd like to update things like drivers. Everything I search for gives Ubuntu solutions. Question one: do Ubuntu and Redhat (or all Linux in general) use the same drivers? Question two: how do I find drivers for my laptop (HP Envy 14, 14T-1100)?

EDIT: To respond to those who have commented, there's a couple things that I would currently consider issues.  The right mouse button on the touchpad doesn't do anything and the screen resolution is locked at SVGA or lower (or something near that).  I haven't tested ethernet but the wireless works.

Comment: Why do you need to update the drivers?

Comment: Drivers are included in the kernel. Are you having some issue?

Comment: I doubt you need to update. I recommend you post a new question asking about your specific problems. Driver updates are not as essential in the *nix world as in Windows.

Comment: Added new info to the original post, labeled EDIT.  I think the original question still pertains...  Are drivers different for different distros?  And, how do I go about finding a driver for a piece of hardware that doesn't work out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question one: do Ubuntu and Redhat (or all Linux in general) use the same drivers?

Essentially, but not exactly.  They're the same in the sense they are compiled from the same (C and asm) source (although distros do sometimes use their own patches).  They're different in the sense that the binaries are not literal copies of each other.  Linux drivers are kernel modules and they are distributed with the kernel. A driver built from a specific kernel version (e.g., 2.6.26 or 3.7.6) for a specific architecture (e.g., x86) *might* work with kernels with the exact same kernel version on the same architecture.

So if you have a ubuntu using 3.11 and a redhat using 3.11 on the same computer, you could probably swap modules back and forth.  However, this would be a sort of academic exercise since the modules are distributed as part of the kernel, and both distros will have built and installed pretty much all of the applicable ones.<sup>1</sup>

> Question two: how do I find drivers for my laptop

You don't have to.  If they exist, they are probably already there.  There are some exceptions, but don't bother with that route unless you absolutely have to for some specific reason.  Drivers which are *not* part of the kernel tree are generally not part of it for a reason, and not a good reason.  There are some exceptions to that -- e.g., ATI and Nvidia make a show of distributing their own OGL drivers, and *where they work*, they should be optimal (although this can be more of a hassle than it is worth).

Ubuntu and Fedora are the two most "up to date" distros in the sense that they frequently upgrade things including the kernel.  Redhat repackages Fedora like Ubuntu repackages Debian.  However, the philosophies are sort of reversed; whereas debian is more conservative in it's approach than ubuntu (hence, less frequent updating), fedora is more radical than redhat (hence, more frequent updating).

Finally, you can compile your own kernel from source on any distro.  This is problematic on the pi because it requires special patches, but with normal desktops and laptops you can use [the real deal](https://www.kernel.org/).  I'm not particularly recommending this, and beware it will take you a fair amount of time to familiarize yourself with all the options...

---

<sup>1</sup> To re-iterate and explain this a bit further: unlike on windows, linux drivers generally aren't supplied by a manufacturer.  They're written by other people and included in the kernel source tree.  All the various distros use the same tree, so **what is significant is not the distro but the kernel version.**

Comment: Alright, thanks, that is good info.  As a novice, then, is it wiser to carefully select hardware that already has support built into a carefully selected distro?  So far I've never played with a distro that gave full use of a touchpad... is the solution to use a USB mouse and ignore drivers?  I'd like to get some screen resolution, but this laptop has both Intel graphics and ATI graphics built in and I can't actually tell which one RH is using by default... I theorize it's using the ATI one and if I could force it onto the Intel one, the stock driver would work.

Comment: "Carefully select hardware" Yes, if you are buying stuff and using it with linux is a priority, doing some research first is a very good idea. "Built into a carefully selected distro" For a general purpose PC, no. It doesn't matter, they are all using the same kernel. The processor is the key in this, which is why there are special distros for the rpi -- they include a kernel patched for it.  There is no such issue with x86(_64) machines.  WRT your touchpad, that is pretty weird since they are all from the same place -- Synaptics  -- using the same driver. I've never seen one not work...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's usually best to isolate hardware that isn't actually working and then narrow focus as to why, and update drivers if needed. Linux isn't like windows in the sense that there are drivers etc. that actively need to be installed/updated.

Rather the drivers and most software is baked into the distro you're using. Things that will "sometimes" require drivers to be installed/updated are for the following hardware:

- network (Ethernet & Wireless)
- Video cards

Everything else should typically just work.